# How do I make a Jquery function that returns a certain View? (NOT Partial View)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page (the customer order View) with a list of items generated from a database (products in a customer purchase order). I want to code it so that if the user clicks on a row (a div element), it will load in a different view, and also provide data based on which row was clicked.

In other words, I want a click event that sends a key value to the controller, and returns the product View along with a model with the relevant data.

Now, if I were to do everything on the same View, I could easily do it with an ajax function, and just return a Partial View into an appropriate element. That, I'm familiar with. But I want to load a whole new View. How do I accomplish this?

Also, for aesthetic reasons, I'd rather not turn the row into a regular link. I'd much rather use a click event.

Comment: If you want a new view, then do a redirect - e.g. using `location.href=yourUrl;`

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTML data attributes on each DIV to store the product ID, e.g.

```
<div class="product-row" data-productid="123">Row content here<div>
```

And then use JQuery to create a click handler that takes the user to the appropriate page. You can use a Razor HTML Helper to construct the URL, but because you don't know which ID they will click ahead of time, you'll have to use a bit of trickery to add the correct Id to the URL:

```
$(document).on('click', '.product-row', function() {
    var productId = $(this).data('productid');
    var url = '@Url.Action("Details", "Product", new { Id = "productId" })';
    var url = url.replace("productId", productId);
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

This will intercept all clicks on the divs, build the URL, and take the user to it.